# Multi page section with title on every page in MigraDoc

Tags: c#, .net, pdfsharp, migradoc

I want a document with multiple pages. Every page should have the same header. One section of the document contains a long table, which stretches over multiple pages. On every page of this section I want to show a title above the table.

I came up with two solutions so far. Both seem hacky and have their downsides:

1. Make the title part of the header in this section. Feels wrong and is also annoying when I have other pages in the document which should contain the header but not the title.
2. Make the title part of the table and use `HeadingFormat`. Feels hacky as well because the title doesn't "fit" in the columns of the table.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re 1: Put the table in a new section and set a new header for that section. One line can be the standard header shared by all pages, another line can be a special header for the table section.
Does not look hacky to me.

Re 2: You can set the HeadingFormat for several rows. So you can use the first row for the "header" without any border and with a MergeRight so it spans the whole page. Not really hacky and will look like normal text outside the table.

Solution 1 has a downside as every new section starts on a new page. Well, the table is so important that it even gets an own page header, so this downside should not matter.

A hacky and tricky solution would be using PDFsharp to add a special header on all pages with the table on it. I think I'd go for option 2.

Comment: I tried using nested tables. Unfortunately MigraDoc cannot split a single `Cell` across multiple pages so I guess I'm stuck with one of your solutions.

Comment: I didn't suggest nested tables. If you need 5 columns in the table, just set `MergeRight=4` for the first cell in the first row and use that as the header.